# Why is Kakfa called pub-sub and can we read randomly from an offset in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, distributed-system

I have been reading about Kafka for weeks now but have some doubts which I was not able to resolve by going through multiple resources. Sorry if these are lame questions.

1. Kafka is a pub-sub system but the consumer pulls data from kafka broker - I have read that pull will be better than pushing (with some cons) but if we are pulling the data why do we call it a pub-sub system? Here Kafka is not notifying the consumers who have subscribed, rather consumer is pulling the data explicitly. (There are resources which say it is called pub-sub because data is not deleted after a consumer reads it (which happen in a queue). However the pub-sub name is still confusing to me).
2. If consumer is pulling data from the broker, then I understand that consumer needs to commit it to the broker (Delivery semantics), but then why do we say that in Kafka, we can start reading from whichever offset we want. I mean broker is keep a track of consumer offset, then to resume reading from a random offset do I need to provide another offset in the API and will the new offset will be reset at the broker's end or how this will happen.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka is a distributed log. The servers are called brokers, and clients are producers and consumers. Calling it "pub sub" makes developers aware what group of problems/applications it can solve/support. It doesn't describe how it's different from other systems in the same group... More importantly, I don't think think "pub sub" is ever written in the official documentation.

> it is called pub-sub because data is not deleted after a consumer reads it

If data is deleted, that describes a **non-persistent queue**, not a pub-sub system.

The main distinction is that there are "Publishers" and "Subscribers" that are not communicating point-to-point. It doesn't matter if the subscription mechanism is push or pull based. [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) -

> In software architecture, publish–subscribe is a messaging pattern where senders of messages, called publishers, do not program the messages to be sent directly to specific receivers, called subscribers, but instead categorize published messages into classes without knowledge of which subscribers, if any, there may be. Similarly, subscribers express interest in one or more classes and only receive messages that are of interest, without knowledge of which publishers, if any, there are.

So, Kafka producers write to ("categorized") topics located on brokers, rather than directly to the consumers ("specific receivers, called subscribers"). Consumers can start reading from topics that don't (yet) exist. And Producers can send data to topics that have no consumer(s).

---

Back to your question -

> to resume reading from a random offset do I need to provide another offset in the API and will the new offset will be reset at the broker's end or how this will happen.

First, consumers aren't required to commit to a consumer group. For any new/expired group, the `auto.offset.reset` config will be used to determine start position, otherwise, the committed offset for an assigned group/topic/partition combination will be used. This is prior to the consumer being able to `seek` individual partitions to random offsets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Publisher subscriber is something which describes that we can subscribe to a topic and we will be notified in case of new data received. That's why if this is not the behaviour, why is it called publisher subscriber if we explicitly pull data from the topic.

Comment: The Kafka Consumer API has a subscribe method... And the documentation describes reading from a topic as subscribing. If you think that is wrong or confusing, it's an open source project. Go file an issue